# Dart implementation of Angular 2 directive ngFor generating error

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart

The following compile time error is generated when trying to use the ngFor directive in the Dart implementation of Angular 2 Beta 0.

```
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded  template ("[ERROR ->]
<div *ngFor="#item of items">
{{item}}
</div>"):
```

Component:

```
library design;

import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'design-component',
    templateUrl: 'design.html',
    viewProviders: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
)
class DesignComponent {
   List<String> items = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="#item of items">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewProviders` should be `directives`. `viewProviders` are for dependency injection.

Comment: I am still getting the same error when trying to use the [ng2_form_examples](https://github.com/ng2-dart-samples/ng2_form_examples) with `Angular 2 Beta`. 

`Property binding ng-forOf not used by any directive on an embedded template` (https://goo.gl/RWSnR7)

Comment: Actually it works for me. I just missed that I had another `ng-for` in the template of my example application. After I changed that to `ngFor` as well all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing:

```
<li *ng-for="#name of friendNames">
```

To:

```
<li *ngFor="#name of friendNames">
```

In my template.

Here is my Component:

```
@Component(selector: "app",
           directives: const [NgFor],
           templateUrl: 'app_component.html')
class AppComponent{
    List<String> friendNames = const ["a", "b", "c"];
}
```

Gunther Zochbauer mentions this in comment to his answer.